# CQL: how to check if keyspace exists?

Tags: cassandra, cql

I need to check if certain keyspace exists in Cassandra database. I need to write smth like this:

```
if (keyspace KEYSPACE_NAME not exists) create keyspace KEYSPACE_NAME;
```

There's a command describe keyspace, but can I somehow retrieve information from it in cql script?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of this moment, [cql grammar](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql/CQL.html#CREATEKEYSPACE) does not provide `create keyspace if not exists`. Probably in the future, they will add this feature. The one come close to this, would be this [improvement](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-2737), maybe they will add in for create keyspace too. *shrugs*

You can probably do something similar using CQL in python or in any Cassandra clients. I have a simple create keyspace if not exists written in java.

```
try
{
    if (cluster.describeKeyspace("new_keyspace") == null)
    {
        System.out.println("create new keyspace");
        KeyspaceDefinition ksdef = HFactory.createKeyspaceDefinition("new_keyspace");
        cluster.addKeyspace(ksdef);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("keyspace exists");
    }
}
catch (HectorException e)
{   
}
```

Comment: Note that from what I know, a `describe*` function is rather slow. Hopefully you do not have to use this too often.

Comment: this was answered back in year 2012... unless at this point of time as of this writing, you are still using ancient cassandra, you should really read the current documentation.

Answer (score 37):

Just providing fresh information. As of [CQL3](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html#createKeyspaceStmt) while creating a keyspace you can add if statement like this

```
CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS Test
    WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy',
                        'replication_factor' : 3}
```

Answer (score 10):

According to: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-2477, as of Cassandra 1.1, you can now do:

```
USE system;
SELECT * FROM schema_keyspaces;
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I just clicked `accept edit` by mistake. Please don't add stuff that changes the context of questions to edits. The `USE system;` in the suggested edit is one such example.

Comment: The problem is that system tables tend to change (quickly) over time. It can be a nightmare to support such code, especially if you have to have legacy support for various users. In CQL 3.x, the info is now in a keyspace named `system_schema`...